# How to create a HTTP proxy handler with Python 3 HTTP lib

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying define a proxy handler to use http.client behind a proxy company. I know just how to use or define a proxy handler to urllib.:

```
http_proxy_full_auth_string = "http://"+"%s:%s@%s:%s" % (http_proxy_user,
                        http_proxy_passwd,
                        http_proxy_server,
                        http_proxy_port)
proxy_handler = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({"http": http_proxy_full_auth_string})
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_handler)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(uri).read()
```

And using http.client...?

P.S: sorry for the low english skills...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [`httplib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection.set_tunnel) python 3 documentation

```
import http.client
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("proxy_domain", 8080)
conn.set_tunnel("www.python.org")
conn.request("HEAD","/index.html")
```

Comment: how to set authenticated proxy?

Answer (score 3):

This might be old thread but folks may stumble upon it like I did and dont know how to authenticate.

```
import http.client
import base64
auth_hash = base64.b64encode(b"username:password").decode("utf-8")

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("proxy-ip or hostname", port="proxy-port")
conn.set_tunnel(
  "example.com", 
  headers={"Proxy-Authorization": f"Basic {auth_hash}"})

conn.request("GET", "/")
```

This is how you do it with basic authentication.