# How to perform post method with data, proxy and headers, using http client?

Tags: python, http, http.client

I find analogue of:

```
response = requests.post(url, data=data, verify=False, proxies=Proxy, headers=header_gen())
```

using `http.client` lib

```
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(url.netloc)
conn.request("POST", url.path, urllib.parse.urlencode({'username': 'admin', 'password': '123'}))
```

Comment: what is the problem? Do you get error message? Always show full error message in question.

Comment: `http.client` may need much more complex code (with much more lines) and this is why people prefer `requests`

Comment: [How to create a HTTP proxy handler with Python 3 HTTP lib - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837102/how-to-create-a-http-proxy-handler-with-python-3-http-lib)